# Tabs for iOS web browsing application [Swift 4]

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, webkit, tabbed-browsing

How would I go about making a web browser application with tabs for multiple websites? I can't find any references or examples online to demonstrate this. I would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Lack of relevant tags...

Comment: Can you add more details and more relevant tags?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzNJfMzjOkQ) a tutorial on how to create a browser. However, it is a single tab browser. To make it multiple tabs, you can create a new `UIView` that has all the functionality of a one page browser every time the user clicks new tab. You can use a segment control (or a collection view that you can design to look like tabs) in order to toggle between the different views.